# O código do wordpress é modificado, mas o blog não atualiza. O que será?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tenho uma duvida não sei como perguntar vou tentar ser clara e objetiva.

Estou aprendendo a editar blogs wordpress e estou usando o theme Ribbon. :
 https://galician-approval.000webhostapp.com/

Porém toda vez que eu edito o código, demora um certo tempo pra atualizar e aparecer as mudanças no blog.

> **O código está lá, mas não aparece no blog.**

Geralmente são quando edito no ***style.css***, ***function.php*** e etc.

Eu edito o blog, ele demora a atualizar, quando atualiza, se eu ficar algumas horas sem editar a theme, o blog 'desatualiza' as mudanças feitas anteriormente, porém quando eu vou no área de wp-admin o código atual está lá. Mas por alguma razão não aparece no blog.

Era pra estar assim (versão atualizada):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra poder voltar ao normal eu preciso ir em algum ficheiro php e clicar em editar e atualizar, assim o blog volta a forma atualizada. 
Porém mesmo fazendo isso, ele fica desatualizado em todos os outros locais. como no meu celular, ou até o anonimo do Google no mesmo computador. Pra ele atualizar eu teria que entrar na conta wp-admin e atualizar os ficheiros de cada dispositivo.

Será um erro meu? Limpei o cache do computador mas ainda assim não mudou. O que faço? Ideias? 
Eu não sei nada de php, estou editando apenas o css, html e javascript do blog wordpress.

Comment: deveria estar assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfJSe.png mas está assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1z1x.png

Comment: [Tem alguma coisa muito errada nisso tudo](https://galician-approval.000webhostapp.com/page/2)

Comment: @MarceloBoni Vi agora que você enviou um link.. Seria erro meu? Ou algo relacionado a cache? Está como se o erro fosse apenas na página principal... Todas as outras estão atualizadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente quando se constrói um site cria-se um sistema de **cache** para suas páginas para evitar que a cada visitante que entre no site tenha que consultar o banco de dados e executar todas as rotinas necessárias para apresentar o mesmo conteúdo novamente. Imagine 10 mil pessoas simultâneas solicitando uma pagina em seu site ao mesmo tempo. Não haveria maquina que suportasse não é? É muito mais fácil, rápido,  escalável e barato fazer isso:

> executar apenas uma vez a rotina e salvar o **arquivo html** e para as próximas requisições que quiserem o mesmo conteúdo durante um determinado tempo apresentar o **html** salvo ao invés de executar tudo novamente.

No wordpress existem centenas de plugins de cache para site é bem provável que você tenha algum configurado, além disso existe o uso de CDN (**Content Delivered Network**) que contam com uma rede de computadores espalhados pelo mundo que trabalham entregando conteúdo estático através de geolocalização ou seja se eu solicito uma página aqui do **Rio de Janeiro** a CDN calcula a rota que contém a página que levaria o menor tempo ou seja, que está mas próximo de mim e me entrega diretamente esse arquivo sem ter que ir até seu servidor. Evitando que a solicitação do usuário seja enviada diretamente a sua alocação e reduzindo o consumo dos recursos da mesma, isso também é um sistema de cache, portanto se usa **cloudflare** ou qualquer outro serviço em nuvem isso também poderia ocasionar o que relatou em sua pergunta.

> A solução para isso é desativar temporariamente o plugin de cache no seu wordpress ou desativar a nuvem (CDN). Todos esses serviços tem um opção para desativar temporariamente o  cache.

Esqueci de um detalhe, só mais uma coisa alguns **provedores de internet** também se utilizam de cache para reduzir o consumo de banda sobre seus servidores.

Atualização:

você está tentando carregar imagens de um domínio **http** (**sem encriptação**) e o dominio que enviou usa **https** (**encriptado**) portanto os navegadores bloqueiam o carregamento por uma questão de segurança.

[image: Veja Aqui]

No código do seu blog corrija para **https** que deve funcionar. No caso das imagens copie para o seu dominio e troque a url no código para **https**.

Isto está acontecendo apenas na sua index conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo a imagem do topo está apontada para outro domínio sem **https**

[image: Index topó URL da imagem errada]

Comment: Uso gvt. Desabilitei os caches do blog. No caso eu precisaria deixar desabilitado até terminar o design do blog pronto certo?

Comment: Está como se o erro fosse apenas na página principal... Todas as outras páginas estão atualizadas. Ainda seria um problema de cache?

Comment: Oi, sim deixe desabilitado enquanto estiver alterando o site em seguida reative o cache.

Comment: Me envie a pagina que ainda exibe a versão antiga para que eu possa ajudar

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta se ainda houver problemas!

Comment: Eu não negativei, mas na sua 'resposta' você confunde alhos com bugalhos... Sobrou até pro coitado do juiz que não entende sobre TI. A única parte que salva é a recomendação de *desativar algum plugin de cache*. Imagina como seria uma plataforma com **N** idiomas fazendo cache de páginas HTML... A melhor alternativa seria usar o cache do navegador.

Comment: Quais partes você acredita não estarem corretas? Quantos sites você tem acima de 100k para começar história? Quantos servidores você gerência?

Comment: Como parte proveitosa da resposta considero coerente recomendar *desativar algum plugin de cache*. A explicação do CDN esta relativamente coerente, mas sobre o cache de arquivos não creio ser conveniente pra plataforma WP, seria melhor usar o cache do próprio navegador para isso e 'cachear' as consultas. São apenas opiniões que podem acrescentar nas própria resposta ;)

Comment: Eu não gerencio nada... sou o juiz que pouco sabe sobre tecnologia. Abraços

Comment: Sim mas a pergunta dela não foi sobre utilizar ou não ! E sim irmão porque as paginas exibem versões antigas. Minha resposta foi no intuito de instruir o que pode ter acontecido citei os plugins e cache, CDN e tb alguns provedores que cacheiam para reduzir o consumo de banda! É revoltante quando se discorda mas não se aponta o erro.Se deseja discordar é direito seu, mas justifique-se!

Comment: Mas eu justifiquei campeão, inclusive concordei com sua sugestão. Está descontando sua raiva do -1 na pessoas errada. Você pode ficar revoltado ou ver como contribuição o tempo que destinei a escrever um comentário - a escolha é sua. Abraços

Comment: @RafaelSalomão https://galician-approval.000webhostapp.com/ a página inical está desatualizada.. Porém ao clicar para ler os posts ou mudar a página lá em baixo, vemos que está atualizado como deveria estar.  O que significa que somente na página inicial é que está desatualizado.

Comment: Sobre sua nova atualização.  Eu já fiz isso, na atualização as fotos são todas do blog teste.  Veja todas as páginas, de menos a inicial, estão atualizadas veja esta https://galician-approval.000webhostapp.com/2017/07/postagem-10 .

Comment: Complementando e resumindo o que @RafaelSalomão postou muitos serviços de hospedagem tem por padrão um sistema de cache que é independente de plugin de _wordpress_. Por parte isso é bom, mas para desenvolvimento da uma dor de cabeça enorme, uma forma de resolver isso é utilizando _plugins_ que gerenciem as atualizações no caso de _frameworks_ ou utilizando por ex: `?v=[rand number]` em caso de código feito a mão.